# How does this compute ? I am trying to understand how the values of H get assigned in the list

Tags: recursion, prolog, backtracking

This predicate should print a list of size `N` containing possible permutations of `0` and `1`.

My question is : does the value of `H` get carried over with each recursion or does the creation of the list with values of `bit(H)` take place in the backtracking phase?

```
bit(0).
bit(1).
gen(0,[]).
gen(N,[H|T]) :-
   N > 0,
   bit(H),
   N1 is N - 1,
   gen(N1,T).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prolog execution is all about choice points. Here a choice point is left at each recursion step by the `bit/1` predicate.
When you ask Prolog to give you another solution, it will just go back to the youngest choice point. Here, instead of going through the first clause of `bit/1` and bind `H` to `0`, it will go through the second clause and bind `H` to `1`. Once both clauses have been picked, Prolog'll go back to an older choice point, etc... until ultimately all choice points are exhausted and the program returns `false.`.

you can try this yourself with the `trace/0` predicate:

```
?- trace, gen(3, Result).
```

Answer (score 2):

May I offer you a more straight forward definition first:

```
gen(N, Xs) :-
   length(Xs, N),
   maplist(between(0,1), Xs).
```

In this definition all recursive parts are now hidden in some built-ins. The first goal ensures that `Xs` is a list of length `N`. And the next goal ensures that each element is between 0 and 1. If you look at the answers, you will realize in what order the solutions are enumerated:

```
?- gen(4, Xs).
   Xs = [0,0,0,0]
;  Xs = [0,0,0,1]
;  Xs = [0,0,1,0]
;  Xs = [0,0,1,1]
;  Xs = [0,1,0,0]
;  Xs = [0,1,0,1]
;  Xs = [0,1,1,0]
;  ... .
```

Answer (score 0):

This predicate generates all numbers (with order) in binary system well to understand it you must understand prolog backtracking, you coudl draw some substitution tree to understand it