# Prolog. Fill out lists

Tags: prolog

I have to fill out a list of length n digits.
I know that n-1 is in the range from 1 to 9,  and one digit can be in the range from 1 to 99.
I did it this way:

```
generate([First|Next],Czynniki):-
    between(1,99,First),
    generate2(Next).

generate2(Next):-
    sublist([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],Next).

sublist([],[]).
sublist([H|T],[H|S]):-
    sublist(T,S).
sublist([_|T],S):-
    sublist(T,S).
```

Doing it this way I generate some of the same solutions. 
Maybe you have some idea  ​​how I can generate lists without repetition?

#### Edit

For the sake of clarity, I (@repeat) have added the following relevant comment by the OP:

> At the entrance I have list of length `N` of undefined variables. And want fill out my list: `N-1` numbers from the interval `1-9` and one number in the range `1-99`.
>
> Example: N=5, L=[56,2,3,4,8] ...

Comment: it's unclear to me what you want to do there. Can precise a little your goal?

Comment: Or at least some examples.  And your code seems incomplete; for one thing, Czynniki only appears once, and there doesn't seem to be any connection between First and Next.

Comment: this funcion generate a lot of the same, good results.
it doesn't generate only one result. For example between generate '2' and sublist generate '3,4,5'. then between generate '3' and sublist '2,4,5' and in the end I have two the same solution: [2,3,4,5] but I want only one.What I have to change here?

Comment: please try to state clearly what you want your predicate to do

Comment: after generate2(Next), I use insert(Next,First,Czynniki) and sort my result.

Comment: At the entrance I have  list of lenght n  undefined variables. And want fill out my list n-1 numbers from the interval 1-9 and one number is is in the range 1-99. Example: n-5, L=[56,2,3,4,8] ...

Answer (score 1):

**Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!**

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Let's define `digits10plusdigit100_n/2` like this:

```
digits10plusdigit100_n(Zs,N) :-
   Zs = [CentDigit|DecDigits],
   length(Zs,N),
   CentDigit in  1..99,
   DecDigits ins 1..9,
   labeling([],Zs).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- digits10plusdigit100_n(Zs,1).
  Zs = [1]
; Zs = [2]
; Zs = [3]
...
; Zs = [98]
; Zs = [99]
; false.

?- digits10plusdigit100_n(Zs,3).
  Zs = [1,1,1]
; Zs = [1,1,2]
; Zs = [1,1,3]
...
; Zs = [1,2,1]
; Zs = [1,2,2]
...
; Zs = [1,9,8]
; Zs = [1,9,9]
; Zs = [2,1,1]
; Zs = [2,1,2]
...
; Zs = [2,1,3]
; Zs = [2,1,4]
...
; Zs = [98,9,9]
; Zs = [99,1,1]
; Zs = [99,1,2]
...
; Zs = [99,9,8]
; Zs = [99,9,9]
; false.
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe change to `between(10,99,X)`
so reverse your predicates, generate numbers less then 10 and then generate last variable wich will be greater then 10

Comment: It doesn't work because X  will not necessarily be greater than 10. The list can consist of a single-digit numbers or n-1 single-digit and one two-digit.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just a variation of what @false very elegantly did in [here ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980581/how-does-this-compute-i-am-trying-to-understand-how-the-values-of-h-get-assign)

```
gen(Xs) :-
       between(1, 9, L),
       length(Xs, L),
       maplist(between(1,99), Xs).

?- gen(Xs).
Xs = [1] ;
Xs = [2] ;
Xs = [3] ;
Xs = [4] ;
Xs = [5] ;
  ..
Xs = [99] ;
Xs = [1, 1] ;
Xs = [1, 2] ;
Xs = [1, 3] ;
Xs = [1, 4] ;
..
Xs = [1, 98] ;
Xs = [1, 99] ;
Xs = [2, 1] ;
Xs = [2, 2] ;
Xs = [2, 3] ;
Xs = [2, 4] ;
Xs = [2, 5] ;
Xs = [2, 6] ;
```

Comment: This is very similar to my but It has a high complexity, and also generates a list with the same content(the list contains the same digits but in a different order).

Comment: Your original question was ambiguous - it stated 'without repetition', but didn't say of what.. per element or per list.  Is this homework /  are there additional constraints / you are not allowed to use built ins like maplist ?

Comment: oh,sory.. Elements in list can be repeated but I don't want to receive the same lists. And I can use everything(also built predicates).
To sum up, at the entrance gives the size of the list(n) and I fill out it (n-1)times single-digit in the range from 1 to 9 (may be repeated), and the last digit is in the range from 1 to 99. 
Best if the list was sorted.